# cronjob to empty a file in a directory

Tags: linux, centos, cron

I have a problem with logs on my web server using apache (centos web panel)
Because it is an API server, once in a few days, the domlogs directory of the server get big enough to crash the server (more than 100gb in logs), so I need to empty the file with the command

```
root@local: cd /var/domlogs
root@local: > logfile.log
```

This will empty the file without breaking the logs link or having to recreate them by restoring logs.

How can I create a cronjob to do the same each X days?

Comment: cron should run the commands through a shell, so you can just use the command and redirection you have there as is. And there's examples of crontab rules in the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html).

Comment: @ilkkachu I am confused, so I should create a .sh files, put the commands there one per line and in crontab execute such file? will it execute the commands one per line? (cd first then > logs)?

Comment: ah, right, you meant that, sorry. No, you can't use multiple lines without putting the script in a file. But `;` works in between, like Mark's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/645309/170373) says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up a crontab for the user ID that runs the apache process, or under the `root` id, where the crontab entry would be like:

```
@daily     cd /var/domlogs; > logfile.log
```

You don't need to create a shell script for a simple task like this; just separate the commands with the `;` character.

The @daily is a GNU extension to run daily at midnight; you can look at https://crontab.guru/ to play with the different parms.

For more specific times, say a on Monday, Wednesday, and Friday at 2:30 AM, try:

```
 30 2 * * 1,3,5   cd /var/domlogs; > logfile.log
```

And here is something I put in the crontab (as comments, for crontab the `#` is a comment, like shell scripts):

```
#Minute   Hour    Day     Month   Wkday   UnixCmd
#0-59     0-23    1-31    1-12    0-7     UnixCmd
```

To set up a cron job for the current user, just use `crontab -e` which will invoke the editor to put in the above commands.

Now, for more advanced tasks, just be aware the various restrictions in cron jobs.  The initial environment has a very limited environment set up as far as `PATH`, etc.   And when the cron job runs, unless the output is redirected to an output file, the standard output and standard error from the task will get emailed to the user that set up the cron.

Comment: I should have followed my own advice, my original post had the parms in the wrong place!  Fixed: See https://crontab.guru/#30_2_*_*_1,3,5

Comment: or with just the full path in the redirection, no need for `cd`. just `30 2 * * 1,3,5   > /var/domlogs/logfile.log`